# "module.exports" works but "export default" not works When Using Dynamic Routing (React-Router)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router

I am using Dynamic Routing in my redux application.
(https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md)

When I want to make a react component dynamically routed, strange things happens. Specifically, below will work:

```
import React from 'react'

class Explore extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Explore</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

module.exports = Explore
```

However, below will not work:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Explore extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Explore</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I use Webpack with babel loader to bundle, so it is very strange, and I could not understand. Other than this, all others work, it means that when I do not use dynamic routing, "export default class" works without problems.

Anyone could shed light on this? Great thanks.

## Updated - below is my Route Configuration:

In Client Main js File:

```
import getDynamicRoutes from './routes.dynamic'

const rootRoute = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  childRoutes: getDynamicRoutes()
}
```

In routes.dynamic.js:

```
export default () => {

  return [
    {
      path: 'explore',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
          cb(null, require('./components/Explore'))
        })
      }
    }, 
    {
      path: 'login',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
          cb(null, require('./containers/Login/Login'))
        })
      }
    },   
    {
      path: 'posts',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
          cb(null, require('./containers/PostList'))
        })
      }
    },  
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add your route configuration?

Comment: @GiladArtzi Thank you, and I have uploaded my route configuration

Comment: As it turns out from this blog post https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/misunderstanding-es6-modules-upgrading-babel-tears-and-a-solution-ad2d5ab93ce0#.nulq4aazy, `require` statement (CommonJS) and `export default` (ES6) don't play well together.

Comment: Got it and Thanks a lot! : )   
No wonder  this project https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/routes.js, uses System.import!

Comment: You are really an expert.